# Is map-editor tag needed?

Tags: discussion, status-deferred, tags

I just came across a tag named [map-editor](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/map-editor) which has no excerpt and wiki to explain what it is intended for.

It seems to be used for a variety of questions.

Is it needed, or could it be made a synonym of another tag?

Answer (score 3):

We have [cartography](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cartography) used in very broad sense (theoretical and practical questions of making maps). We also have [maps](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maps) which overlaps with cartography, but "maps" is more close about the product/output of "cartography". Cartography is more close to the science behind the action of making maps. Perhaps we could clarify on their excerpt when to use one, and the other. Also, note we have [map](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/map) which was made a synonym of "cartography", the excerpt on that tag is closest to "cartography", but the tag name is closest to "maps". Perhaps something should be done to avoid this confusion.

On the other hand, [map-editor](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/map-editor) makes sense to me for questions about the set of software that allows creation and edition of maps. Remembering that a question not necessarily needs to be about a specific software.

Also, it would be necessary some actions to make the tag work, for example: filling excerpt and wiki, tagging key questions about map-editors to provide guidance (not necessary to massive tag backwards), remove the tag where it was incorrectly used (there are few posts to review).

Comment: 'a question not necessarily needs to be about a specific software.' +1

Answer (score 1):

When I came across the [map-editor](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/map-editor) tag, which has been used on 13 questions, my confusion revolved around whether it might be related to:

- Map Authoring where we already have [print-composer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/print-composer), [layouts](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/layouts) and perhaps others;
- Data Editing where we already have [editing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/editing) and perhaps others; or
- perhaps a product called Map Editor, or a component of that name in a GIS platform.  The term ["map editor" has been used in 12 questions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22map%20editor%22%20is%3Aquestion) but only two of these have been tagged [map-editor](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/map-editor).

A quick analysis of how the current questions group within the above three categories is:

- Map Authoring

  - [OpenStreetMap Style Editor besides Mapbox TileMill and CloudMade](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163865/openstreetmap-style-editor-besides-mapbox-tilemill-and-cloudmade)
  - [Create css Flex Module Edition](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120552/create-css-flex-module-edition)
- Data Editing

  - [Editor Tool, Areas instead of Segments in ArcMap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/201543/editor-tool-areas-instead-of-segments-in-arcmap)
  - https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173351/how-to-create-a-fantasy-map
  - [How to stop QGIS auto snapping new poly lines as they are being created?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/168032/how-to-stop-qgis-auto-snapping-new-poly-lines-as-they-are-being-created)
  - [How can I edit gpx tracks, property timestamp and waypoints?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/162005/how-can-i-edit-gpx-tracks-property-timestamp-and-waypoints)
  - [ArcGIS JS api - how to hide attributes editor when new graphic is added](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/135693/arcgis-js-api-how-to-hide-attributes-editor-when-new-graphic-is-added)
  - [Finding shape editing tools for Ubuntu](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133980/finding-shape-editing-tools-for-ubuntu)
  - [How to find if ArcMap raised error during edit session?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118176/how-to-find-if-arcmap-raised-error-during-edit-session)
  - [Seeking online WKT editor?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60534/are-there-any-online-wkt-editors)
  - [What GIS editors work with GIS data that is stored in SQL-Server](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/317/what-gis-editors-work-with-gis-data-that-is-stored-in-sql-server)
- "map editor" product/component

  - [Is there a decent open source map-editor?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/187/is-there-a-decent-open-source-map-editor)
  - [What datastructure is a good choice for objects in a map-editor?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61/what-datastructure-is-a-good-choice-for-objects-in-a-map-editor)

From this, even if I have 2-3 in debatable categories, I think it seems that the [map-editing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/map-editing) tag could perhaps be made a synonym of [editing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/editing).

However, if there is a product/component that someone wants to write up a tag wiki for then I would also be supportive of that, with most of the above being retagged away from it.